# My mails originated from Gmail are going to recepients Spam folder

Tags: email, spam, gmail

I added my company's email to my Gmail account. I can send my emails using my company email via "Send Mail As" function of Gmail.

Some of my emails are directly going to recepients' Spam folder.

None of the emails contain marketing material.

Is there a way to test why those mails labeled as Spam?

UPDATE:

This is the summary from isnotspam.com:

```
==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================

SPF Check : softfail
Sender-ID Check : neutral
DKIM Check : invalid
SpamAssassin Check : ham (non-spam)
```

What should I do now?

Comment: there is a service called Is Not Spam -  http://isnotspam.com/ (not an endorsement - never used them)